# How to convert an x-www-form-urlencoded string to JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Exampple of application/x-www-form-urlencoded string

```
CorrelationId=1&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=1&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=2&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=3&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=4
```

<sub>(Decoded)</sub>

```
CorrelationId=1&PickedNumbers[]=1&PickedNumbers[]=2&PickedNumbers[]=3&PickedNumbers[]=4
```

Into JSON

```
var gamePlayData = {
            CorrelationId: gameId,
            PickedNumbers: ["1","2","3","4"]
        };
```

Answer (score 37):

This is a core module of Node.js now: https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options

```
var qs = require('querystring')

var json = qs.parse('why=not&sad=salad')
    // { why: 'not', sad: 'salad' }
```

Works with encoded characters too:

```
var json2 = qs.parse('http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&sad=salad')
    // { url: 'http://example.com', sad: 'salad' }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Year 2022: querystring is deprecated. Use URLSearchParams instead. Works also in the browser.

Comment: Really?! Dam, I keep using `querystring` Example?

Comment: Note, both querystring and URLSearchParams will give you `'PickedNumbers[]': [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ]` whereas OP asked for solution that will give you `PickedNumbers: ["1","2","3","4"]` which is a flavour of www-form notation specific for php and few other environments.

Answer (score 16):

I've been dealing with this recently: I had to parse data that could contain objects nested up to 5 levels deep. I needed the code to be able to deal with both rather complex data, but not fail to decode a URI as simple as `id=213`.

I spent quite some time on google, trying to find a (semi-)elegant solution to this problem, and this question kept showing up. Since it gets 1 view/day (give or take) I've decided to post my solution here, hope it helps someone out:

```
function form2Json(str)
{
    "use strict";
    var obj,i,pt,keys,j,ev;
    if (typeof form2Json.br !== 'function')
    {
        form2Json.br = function(repl)
        {
            if (repl.indexOf(']') !== -1)
            {
                return repl.replace(/\](.+?)(,|$)/g,function($1,$2,$3)
                {
                    return form2Json.br($2+'}'+$3);
                });
            }
            return repl;
        };
    }
    str = '{"'+(str.indexOf('%') !== -1 ? decodeURI(str) : str)+'"}';
    obj = str.replace(/\=/g,'":"').replace(/&/g,'","').replace(/\[/g,'":{"');
    obj = JSON.parse(obj.replace(/\](.+?)(,|$)/g,function($1,$2,$3){ return form2Json.br($2+'}'+$3);}));
    pt = ('&'+str).replace(/(\[|\]|\=)/g,'"$1"').replace(/\]"+/g,']').replace(/&([^\[\=]+?)(\[|\=)/g,'"&["$1]$2');
    pt = (pt + '"').replace(/^"&/,'').split('&');
    for (i=0;i<pt.length;i++)
    {
        ev = obj;
        keys = pt[i].match(/(?!:(\["))([^"]+?)(?=("\]))/g);
        for (j=0;j<keys.length;j++)
        {
            if (!ev.hasOwnProperty(keys[j]))
            {
                if (keys.length > (j + 1))
                {
                    ev[keys[j]] = {};
                }
                else
                {
                    ev[keys[j]] = pt[i].split('=')[1].replace(/"/g,'');
                    break;
                }
            }
            ev = ev[keys[j]];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I've tested it, with data like the string below (4 levels deep):

```
str  = "id=007&name[first]=james&name[last]=bond&name[title]=agent&personalia[occupation]=spy&personalia[strength]=women&personalia[weakness]=women&tools[weapons][close][silent]=garrot&tools[weapons][medium][silent]=pistol_supressed&tools[weapons][medium][loud]=smg&tools[weapons][far][silent]=sniper&tools[movement][slow]=foot&tools[movement][far]=DBS";
```

Which neatly returns an object, that, when passed through `JSON.stringify` comes out like this:

```
{"id":"007","name":{"title":"agent","first":"james","last":"bond"},"personalia":{"weakness":"women","occupation":"spy","strength":"women"},"tools":{"movement":{"far":"DBS","slow":"foot"},"weapons":{"close":{"silent":"garrot"},"medium":{"silent":"pistol_supressed","loud":"smg"},"far":{"silent":"sniper"}}}}
```

It passes a JSlint check, when ignoring white space, `.` and `[^...]` and accepting `++`. All in all, I'd consider that to be acceptable.

Comment: I am getting  ReferenceError: form2Json is not defined at line if (typeof form2Json.br !== 'function')

Comment: You're the best. :)

Comment: The code doesn't work correctly if your data contains square brackets, or even quote marks `str =  "id=007%22";` will cause error

Comment: Please use real variable names for examples. This allows other people to read the code in your answers.

Comment: Does it account for nested arrays?

Answer (score 15):

You can use [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) library if you're using node, or browserify.

```
var qs = require('qs')
var encodedString = "CorrelationId=1&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=1&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=2&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=3&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=4" 

console.log(qs.parse(encodedString))
// { CorrelationId: '1', PickedNumbers: [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ] }
```

Comment: In node you can use the built in `querystring` https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

Answer (score 6):

the following code should do the trick:

```
var str = 'CorrelationId=1&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=1&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=2&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=3&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=4';
var keyValuePairs = str.split('&');
var json = {};
for(var i=0,len = keyValuePairs.length,tmp,key,value;i <len;i++) {
    tmp = keyValuePairs[i].split('=');
    key = decodeURIComponent(tmp[0]);
    value = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
    if(key.search(/\[\]$/) != -1) {
        tmp = key.replace(/\[\]$/,'');
        json[tmp] = json[tmp] || [];
        json[tmp].push(value);
    }
    else {
        json[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer for 2022, works both in the browser and in node.
Use `URLSearchParams` class.

> Note: The param name `PickedNumbers%5B%5D` will turn to be the literal string `PickedNumbers[]`. You don't need to encode the brackets in order to make it an array

```js
    const paramsStr = 'CorrelationId=1&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=1&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=2&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=3&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=4';
    const params = new URLSearchParams(paramsStr);
    //access a specific param
    console.log(params.get('PickedNumbers[]')); // '4'
    console.log(params.getAll('PickedNumbers[]')); // ['1','2','3','4']
     const o = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(params.keys()).map(k => [k, params.getAll(k).length===1 ? params.get(k) : params.getAll(k)]));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(o)); //full object
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pure-JavaScript way to do it. JavaScript frameworks might also help you out with this. **EDIT:** Just for kicks, I threw in dictionary parsing, too. See the 2nd example.

```
function decodeFormParams(params) {
  var pairs = params.split('&'),
      result = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    var pair = pairs[i].split('='),
        key = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]),
        value = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]),
        isArray = /\[\]$/.test(key),
        dictMatch = key.match(/^(.+)\[([^\]]+)\]$/);

    if (dictMatch) {
      key = dictMatch[1];
      var subkey = dictMatch[2];

      result[key] = result[key] || {};
      result[key][subkey] = value;
    } else if (isArray) {
      key = key.substring(0, key.length-2);
      result[key] = result[key] || [];
      result[key].push(value);
    } else {
      result[key] = value;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

decodeFormParams("CorrelationId=1&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=1&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=2&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=3&PickedNumbers%5B%5D=4");
// => {"CorrelationId":"1","PickedNumbers":["1","2","3","4"]}

decodeFormParams("a%5Bb%5D=c&a%5Bd%5D=e");
// => {"a":{"b":"c","d":"e"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner:

```js
let s = 'a=1&b=2&c=3';

Object.fromEntries(
  s.split('&')
   .map(s => s.split('='))
   .map(pair => pair.map(decodeURIComponent)))

// -> {a: "1", b: "2", c: "3"}
```

and if you want repeated parameters to be represented as arrays:

```js
let s = 'a=1&b=2&c[]=3&c[]=4&c[]=5&c[]=6';

s
  .split('&')
  .map(s => s.split('='))
  .map(pair => pair.map(decodeURIComponent))
  .reduce((memo, [key, value]) => { 
    if (!(key in memo)) { memo[key] = value; } 
    else { 
      if (!(memo[key] instanceof Array)) 
        memo[key] = [memo[key], value]; 
        else 
        memo[key].push(value); 
      } 
    return memo; 
}, {})

// -> {"a":"1","b":"2","c[]":["3","4","5","6"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this->

```
// convert string to object
str = 'a=6&id=99';
var arr = str.split('&');
var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var bits = arr[i].split('=');
    obj[bits[0]] = bits[1];
}
//alert(obj.a);
//alert(obj.id);

// convert object back to string
str = '';
for(key in obj) {
    str += key + '=' + obj[key] + '&';
}
str = str.slice(0, str.length - 1); 
alert(str);
```

Or use this (JQuery) http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: jQuery.param does serialization - and the question was about inverse operation.

Answer (score 0):

You need the opposite of jQuery.param. One of the options is http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonMessage = "{\"".concat(message.replace("&", "\",\"").replace("=", "\":\"")).concat("\"}");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In typescript, works for me: 
Use qs.parse to transform in object ParsedQs.
Use as unknow to implicit type unknow and before force convert to string.
Use JSON.parse to convert an string to object.
It was useful to use validations with [Joi](https://joi.dev/).

```
const payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(qs.parse(request.body) as unknown as string));
```

Payload (cURL):

```
--data-urlencode 'notification=123-456123' \
--data-urlencode 'test=123456' \
--data-urlencode 'ajieoajeoa=Lorem ipsum'
```

Result:

```
{
  notification: '123-456123',
  test: '123456',
  ajieoajeoa: 'Lorem ipsum'
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
public static void Main()

{
```

string str ="RESULT=0&PNREF=A10AABBF8DF2&RESPMSG=Approved&AUTHCODE=668PNI&PREFPSMSG=No Rules Triggered&POSTFPSMSG=No Rules Triggered";

```
    var sr = str.Replace("&", "=");

    string[] sp = sr.Split('=');

    var spl = sp.Length;

    int n = 1;

    var ss = "{";

    for (var k = 0; k < spl; k++)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (n == spl)
            {
                ss += '"' + sp[k] + '"';
            }
            else
            {
                ss += '"' + sp[k] + '"' + ",";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ss += '"' + sp[k] + '"' + ":";
        }
        n++;
    }
    ss += "}";
    Console.WriteLine(ss);
}
```

Comment: It will be better if you add some explanation