# How do I convert x-www-form-urlencoded into json data?

Tags: json

I am trying to convert x-www-form-urlencoded into json.
In the form I have a key and a value. Key as a queryFilter and the value corresponding to that. I also have a header as a cookie. When i tried in x-www-form-urlencoded it gives me right response.But it gives me 400 status when i tried as a raw in Json. Can any one please help me convert x-www-form-urlencoded to  JSON?

Comment: Hi @iahsiba, any success ?? I also need to convert into JSON.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671985/how-to-convert-an-x-www-form-urlencoded-string-to-json