# how to parse parameter in http request and get response in node

Tags: node.js, http, curl

I want to get result by HTTP request in which I would like to know how can I parse the post parameter in the same and get the result.

```
var http    = require("http");
var email   = "email";
var password  = '12345';       
var response_string='010000000157065146a6b32b224b87d47c1b0283b1ae2fa5bd4f9af9ebc45928110f87fbae00000000700';
var post_params="jsonrpc= 1.0&id=curltest&method=decoderawtransaction&params="+response_string;

http.request({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port:"8332",
    path:"/path",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {                   
        "Authorization": "Basic " + new Buffer( email + ":" + password ).toString('base64')
        }
    }, function(res){
        var response = "";

        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            response += chunk;
            console.log("res"+response);
        });

        res.on('end',function(){
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log("res1"+response);                   
        });
}).end();
```

How can i parse the post_params variable in request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an x-www-form-urlencoded string to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671985/how-to-convert-an-x-www-form-urlencoded-string-to-json)

Comment: can't you just use `req.query.<name of param>` or `req.params`? Alternatively, if it's a header you can use `req.headers` to retrieve the headers.