# How to parse a string received via a get request using form2Json?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I get the error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token: in JSON at position 5759 (line 42)

on the first request, and on the second everything is fine, what could be the problem and how can it be solved?

```
function myFunction() {
var one = "leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=30896454&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%8F+%28%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%29+23.11.2021+12%3A30&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bstatus_id%5D=33131353&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bold_status_id%5D=33131347&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bprice%5D=0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bresponsible_user_id%5D=7490283&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Blast_modified%5D=1637662097&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bmodified_user_id%5D=0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcreated_user_id%5D=0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bdate_create%5D=1636435650&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bpipeline_id%5D=1635139&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=451580&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=tilda&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=469607&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B2%5D%5Bid%5D=475269&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B3%5D%5Bid%5D=476169&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B4%5D%5Bid%5D=480372&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%92%D0%A3&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B5%5D%5Bid%5D=483228&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+%2B2&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B6%5D%5Bid%5D=485614&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B7%5D%5Bid%5D=486524&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%97%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA+%C2%AB%D0%9B%C2%BB&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B8%5D%5Bid%5D=486530&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B9%5D%5Bid%5D=487240&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9F%D0%9A&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B10%5D%5Bid%5D=490756&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B10%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B11%5D%5Bid%5D=493262&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B11%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%B2+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Baccount_id%5D=24809335&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=683303&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=utm_referrer&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcode%5D=UTM_REFERRER&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=681646&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%2C+Yclients&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE+%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%8F&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B2%5D%5Bid%5D=681648&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B%2C+Yclients&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B2%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=45+%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD.&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B3%5D%5Bid%5D=928932&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80+1+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B3%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%D0%93%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B3%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Benum%5D=4204978&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B4%5D%5Bid%5D=678201&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B4%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B5%5D%5Bid%5D=913962&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B5%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=6&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B5%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Benum%5D=4198694&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B6%5D%5Bid%5D=681336&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD+%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B6%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%D0%97%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B6%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Benum%5D=4188232&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B7%5D%5Bid%5D=673089&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=ID+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%2C+Yclients&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B7%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=290330-375075392&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B8%5D%5Bid%5D=673093&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%2C+Yclients&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B8%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=23.11.2021&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B9%5D%5Bid%5D=673091&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%2C+Yclients&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B9%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=12%3A30&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B10%5D%5Bid%5D=928936&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B10%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+%28%D0%A2%29&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B10%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D=1636405200&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B11%5D%5Bid%5D=928940&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B11%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D0%92%D0%A3+%28%D0%A2%29&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B11%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D=1637528400&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B12%5D%5Bid%5D=928942&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B12%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%BE+%28%D0%A2%29&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B12%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D=1637614800&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B13%5D%5Bid%5D=928944&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B13%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5+%28%D0%A2%29&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B13%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D=1636405200&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B14%5D%5Bid%5D=670612&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B14%5D%5Bname%5D=REFERER&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B14%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fmylogoped.online%2Freading%3Futm_source%3Dblogger%26amp%3Butm_campaign%3Ddaria_moguchaya%26amp%3Butm_medium%3Drg%23rec319161715&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B15%5D%5Bid%5D=680880&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B15%5D%5Bname%5D=FORMNAME&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B15%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B15%5D%5Bcode%5D=FORMNAME&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B16%5D%5Bid%5D=671845&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B16%5D%5Bname%5D=UTM_SOURCE&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B16%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=blogger&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B17%5D%5Bid%5D=671847&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B17%5D%5Bname%5D=UTM_MEDIUM&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B17%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=rg&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B18%5D%5Bid%5D=671849&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B18%5D%5Bname%5D=UTM_CAMPAIGN&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B18%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=daria_moguchaya&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B19%5D%5Bid%5D=670608&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B19%5D%5Bname%5D=TRANID&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B19%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=2225828%3A2655884701&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B20%5D%5Bid%5D=670610&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B20%5D%5Bname%5D=FORMID&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B20%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=form319161715&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcreated_at%5D=1636435650&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bupdated_at%5D=1637662097&account%5Bsubdomain%5D=mylogoped&account%5Bid%5D=24809335&account%5B_links%5D%5Bself%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fmylogoped.amocrm.ru";
var two = "leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=30983426&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=Lead+from%3A+https%3A%2F%2Fmylogoped.online%2F%23rec367114784&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bstatus_id%5D=24809344&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bprice%5D=0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bresponsible_user_id%5D=7420479&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Blast_modified%5D=1637662184&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bmodified_user_id%5D=7420479&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcreated_user_id%5D=0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bdate_create%5D=1637661669&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bpipeline_id%5D=1635139&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=451580&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=tilda&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=475269&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B2%5D%5Bid%5D=476169&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B3%5D%5Bid%5D=483228&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+%2B2&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B4%5D%5Bid%5D=493262&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%B2+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Baccount_id%5D=24809335&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=683303&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=utm_referrer&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcode%5D=UTM_REFERRER&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=928932&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80+1+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B0&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Benum%5D=4205136&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B2%5D%5Bid%5D=681336&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD+%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B2%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%D0%97%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B2%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Benum%5D=4188232&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B3%5D%5Bid%5D=670612&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=REFERER&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B3%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fmylogoped.online%2F%23rec367114784&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B4%5D%5Bid%5D=670608&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=TRANID&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B4%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=2225828%3A2723274121&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B5%5D%5Bid%5D=670610&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=FORMID&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B5%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=form367114784&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcreated_at%5D=1637661669&leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bupdated_at%5D=1637662184&account%5Bsubdomain%5D=mylogoped&account%5Bid%5D=24809335&account%5B_links%5D%5Bself%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fmylogoped.amocrm.ru";
Logger.log(form2Json(one));
}
```

Here is the form2Json script itself

```
 /**
 *
 * @file Parse data that could contain objects nested up to 5 levels deep.
 * It's able to deal with both rather complex data, but not fail to decode a URI as simple as id=213.
 * @author Elias Van Ootegem {@link https://stackoverflow.com/users/1230836/elias-van-ootegem}
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10881657/1393023
 */

/**
 *
 * @param {string} formString
 * @return {object}
 */
function form2Json(formString) {
  'use strict';
  let obj;
  let i;
  let pt;
  let keys;
  let j;
  let ev;
  if (typeof form2Json.br !== 'function') {
    form2Json.br = function(repl) {
      if (repl.indexOf(']') !== -1) {
        return repl.replace(/\](.+?)(,|$)/g, function($1, $2, $3) {
          return form2Json.br($2 + '}' + $3);
        });
      }
      return repl;
    };
  }
  formString =
    '{"' +
    (formString.indexOf('%') !== -1
      ? decodeURIComponent(formString)
      : formString) +
    '"}';
  obj = formString
    .replace(/\=/g, '":"')
    .replace(/&/g, '","')
    .replace(/\[/g, '":{"');
  obj = JSON.parse(
    obj.replace(/\](.+?)(,|$)/g, function($1, $2, $3) {
      return form2Json.br($2 + '}' + $3);
    })
  );
  pt = ('&' + formString)
    .replace(/(\[|\]|\=)/g, '"$1"')
    .replace(/\]"+/g, ']')
    .replace(/&([^\[\=]+?)(\[|\=)/g, '"&["$1]$2');
  pt = (pt + '"').replace(/^"&/, '').split('&');
  for (i = 0; i < pt.length; i++) {
    ev = obj;
    keys = pt[i].match(/(?!:(\["))([^"]+?)(?=("\]))/g);
    for (j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
      if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(ev, keys[j])) {
        if (keys.length > j + 1) {
          ev[keys[j]] = {};
        } else {
          ev[keys[j]] = pt[i].split('=')[1].replace(/"/g, '');
          break;
        }
      }
      ev = ev[keys[j]];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the form value

```js
leads[update][0][custom_fields][14][values][0][value]
```

The following section of your string:

```js
leads%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B14%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fmylogoped.online%2Freading%3Futm_source%3Dblogger
```

will become decoded to the following:

```js
leads[update][0][custom_fields][14][values][0][value]=https://mylogoped.online/reading?utm_source=blogger
```

The incriminating value being the url:

```js
https://mylogoped.online/reading?utm_source=blogger
```

form2Json attempts to create a JSON object out of the string using conventional replacement methods:

```js
formString =
    '{"' +
    (formString.indexOf('%') !== -1
        ? decodeURIComponent(formString)
        : formString) +
    '"}';

obj = formString
    .replace(/\=/g, '":"')
    .replace(/&/g, '","')
    .replace(/\[/g, '":{"');
```

Where `formString` is the string you pass to it (in your case, `one`).

Due to the line `.replace(/\=/g, '":"')` the `=` signifying a URL parametergets converted to a `":"`, and so then in the string that is provided to `JSON.parse()` reads:

```js
"leads": {
  "update": {
    "0": {
      "custom_fields": {
        "14": {
          "values": {
            "0": {
              "value": "https://mylogoped.online/reading?utm_source": "blogger"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which is an invalid JSON string and throws the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 5759
```

#### Fix:

You need to encode the `=` in the URL before putting it into `form2Json` in some way

Perhaps change all `=` characters in the raw input to a different character string (such as `{{ EQUALS_SIGN }}`) and then after calling `form2Json(one)` replace all instances of the `{{ EQUALS_SIGN }}` string for an `=` whenever it is to be displayed anywhere

Comment: Please tell me why the second line works without errors? because there is also a symbol =

Comment: It's not the symbol `=` specifically - it's the `=` inside the URL `https://mylogoped.online/reading?utm_source=blogger`. form2Json can't deal with the `=` sign inside a value.

Comment: The value is `https%3A%2F%2Fmylogoped.online%2Freading%3Futm_source%3Dblogger`. The `%3D` gets converted to an `=` when it gets URL decoded (try it out [here](https://www.urldecoder.org/)) and then form2Json converts *that* `=` to the string `":"`. This makes the value in the JSON structure `"https://mylogoped.online/reading?utm_source": "blogger"` which is not valid as the  string ends too early and adds an erroneous `:` token.

Comment: Thank you, now I realized that I was looking in the wrong place, but I cannot decode it, because I receive data through a webhook, maybe there is some way to take the data differently?

Comment: And if you apply from String.replace to the received data before using the function, I think it should work, thank you very much, I will try, but if you have an idea better, I’ll listen with pleasure) thanks)

Comment: Good afternoon, tell me, I removed the link from the request, and I still get an error

Comment: @КостяКоростелев it’s possible there are also some additional parsing issues (curly brackets, for example) so in this case it might be better to ask a new question to bring it more attention ))